# How to cut first characters until a special character found?

Tags: python, text-formatting

I have 100 lines where each line consists of some sentences.Each line starts with some characters followed by  `-rrb-`.

How can I format the text so that each line actually starts after the  `-rrb-`.

Line Example:

> Lorem ipsum -lrb- dolor -rrb- sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis dolor a sapien efficitur fermentum egestas ut elit. Nulla porttitor diam id orci bibendum volutpat. Quisque imperdiet euismod neque in efficitur.

I want for this and every line:

> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis dolor a sapien efficitur fermentum egestas ut elit. Nulla porttitor diam id orci bibendum volutpat. Quisque imperdiet euismod neque in efficitur.

So I want to start this and every 100 lines from the word after `-rrb-` (
"sit" for this example).

Comment: what did you try? where is the code you have problems with?

Comment: Can you paste 1 sample of i/p and expected o/p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just index it out:

```
print(s[s.index('-rrb-')+6:])
```

Output:

```
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis dolor a sapien efficitur fermentum egestas ut elit. Nulla porttitor diam id orci bibendum volutpat. Quisque imperdiet euismod neque in efficitur.
```

Comment: It looks like only this answer takes into account the multiple existence of  '-rrb-' in a line.

Answer (score 3):

Use split:

```
text = line.split('-rrb-', 1)[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**@NavaW**, you can try the below code to get the sentence after **-rrb-** for 1 line.

Finally you can loop over 100 lines and process each lines.

```
line = "Lorem ipsum -lrb- dolor -rrb- sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis dolor a sapien efficitur fermentum egestas ut elit. Nulla porttitor diam id orci bibendum volutpat. Quisque imperdiet euismod neque in efficitur."
new_line = line.split("-rrb-")[1].strip()
print(new_line)

"""
sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis dolor a sapien efficitur fermentum egestas ut elit. Nulla porttitor diam id orci bibendum volutpat. Quisque imperdiet euismod neque in efficitur.
"""
```